# Javascript Variable Scope. How Do I Access an Object Var From an Internal Object Function?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to access the "nam"e variable with a function in a javascript object like so:

```
function myObj() {
    this.vars = {
        name: 'bob',
        age: '42'
    }
    this.functions = {
        sayName: function() {
            alert(this.vars.name);
        }
    }
}

var obj = new myObj();
obj.functions.sayName();
```

What am I missing here?

I can get the name var if I pass a reference to itself like:

```
function myObj() {
    this.vars = {
        name: 'bob',
        age: '42'
    }
    this.functions = {
        sayName: function(name) {
            alert(name);
        }
    }
}

var obj = new myObj();
obj.functions.sayName(obj.vars.name);
```

but that seems a little redundant... thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that in your function `this.functions.sayName`, the `this` keyword refers to `this.functions` instead of the current object<sup>1</sup>.

Here is a fix for that issue:

```
function myObj() {
    var vars = this.vars = {
        name: 'bob',
        age: '42'
    }
    this.functions = {
        sayName: function() {
            alert(vars.name);
        }
    }
}

var obj = new myObj();
obj.functions.sayName();
```

This creates a local variable inside of `myObj` that you can access from any inner scope. It also exposes that variable to the outside world as a property of any instantiated `myObj` class, which means you can still do something like

```
obj.vars.name = 'test';
```

and it will still change the internal state of the object. That's probably the best solution for your current setup.

<sup>1</sup> The behavior of the `this` keyword in JavaScript is interesting. I recommend the excellent [writeup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) at the Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: awesome answer.  I do indeed need to keep the variables accessible to outside components so adding the this.vars = is key.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var thisObj = this;
this.functions = {
    sayName: function() {
        alert(thisObj.vars.name);
    }
}
```

Not sure if that's the best solution, but it works.  The Javascript *this* always refers to the internal scope if you're inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `this`:

```
function myObj() {
    var vars = {
        name: 'bob',
        age: '42'
    };
    this.functions = {
        sayName: function() {
            alert(vars.name);
        }
    };
};

var obj = new myObj();
obj.functions.sayName();​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LGDtp/3)

Comment: That creates an implicit global and decouples the `vars` object from any specific object. If you instantiate another `myObj`, you end up having multiple objects share state.

Comment: @Reid. I had a small mistake, take a look on the updated fiddle.